# Несколько mime type в intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent, mime, типы

Передаю из приложения картинку и текст.
Как указать несколько типов?
Вариант "**/**" - не подходит, так как он дает слишком большой список выбора.
Нужно получить комбинированный список с "text/plain" и "image/*"

Comment: ImageView ...img пробовли ?даете в метод а метод в nput

Comment: данные я передаю через putExtra.  
Мне нужно intent изменить

Comment: Я понел а что вм мешает в пут добавть метод с ключем? или какойнибудь мап

Comment: как это повлияет на отображение списка приложений, по обработке intent?

Comment: @Jorik А как, по Вашему, целевое приложение поймёт что от него хотят?

Comment: @Jorik можно запросить отдельно оба списка, объединить и вывести в своём  диалоге

Comment: а как сделать подобное, но не объеденить эти списки, а вывести пересекающиеся